Azure Data Factory: ErrorCode=DelimitedTextMoreColumnsThanDefined in Copy Activity
I'm encountering an issue while trying to copy a csv file from an SFTP server to Blob Storage using Azure Data Factory (ADF) Copy Activity. The specific error message I'm receiving is as follows:

ErrorCode=DelimitedTextMoreColumnsThanDefined,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=Error found when processing 'Csv/Tsv Format Text' source 'CRM_XXX_###.CSV' with row number 1140713: found more columns than expected column count 369.,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common,'

Context:

I'm using Azure Data Factory to copy CSV file from an SFTP server to Azure Blob Storage.
The CSV file 'CRM_XXX-###.CSV' is quite large and contains many rows (3.8 GB).
The specified column count in the dataset schema is 369.

Problem:

The error occurs at row number 1,140,713 where it seems to find more columns than expected (more than 369 columns).
This error halts the copy activity, preventing the file from being fully processed and copied.

Steps I've Taken:

Checked the dataset schema in ADF to ensure the column count is set to 369.
Verified the CSV file format and structure to confirm it adheres to the expected column count.
Tried to locate and inspect the problematic row (1,140,713) in the CSV file but couldn't identify any anomalies manually as the file is too big.

Questions:

What could be causing this discrepancy in the column count?
Are there any best practices or tools to handle or preprocess large CSV files to avoid such issues in ADF?
Is there a way to configure ADF to skip or log the problematic rows instead of failing the entire copy activity?

Additional Information:

The source file is quite large (several million rows).
Manually inspecting the entire file is not feasible due to its size.
My csv file uses | for seperator

Any insights or suggestions on how to resolve or work around this issue would be greatly appreciated!
Screenshots:
I assume that the quote/escape characters need to be changed.
Source Dataset:

Sink Dataset:


It hasnt helped me solve the problem Naveen.

@redwolf_cr7 Are you not able to log the error records separately? If error records are stored in the blob storage, from there you can check which row is causing the issue.

I am able to log the records but they are incomprehensible.

The error message indicates that the CSV file contains more columns than expected. This could be caused by any of the below reasons.

The CSV file contains extra delimiters (in your case, "|") that are not part of the data.
The CSV file contains unescaped delimiters within the data that are being interpreted as column separators.
The CSV file contains multi-line fields that are not properly enclosed in quotes.

Since it is a huge file, you cannot check the error causing row manually. You can enable fault tolerance in copy activity. Below is the approach to do.

Click the settings tab in the copy activity.
In Fault tolerance, Select  Skip incompatible rows. This will skip all the rows which causes issue.
Click the enable logging check box.
Give the storage linked service name in the storage connection name.
In the logging level, select Warning only. This will only log the skipped incompatible rows in the log file.(storage file)


